# Excel split cell

Tags: excel, vba, function

I'm trying to split the below data in EXCEL but unable to get the required result.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Abc | ABC | Abc |
| BCD Bcd Cde | BCD | Bcd Cde |
| CDE EFG Cde | CDE EFG | Cde |

Colum A to be splitted as mentioned in B and C column

> B Column will have data of all capital words before space of capitlize word

> C column will have Cap words

Comment: How are you trying to split it - using VBA or formulae? In either case - post your attempts and results

Comment: ... and whern you are editing your question to post what you have tried, please also explain the processing logic that leads to the result. Plain words will do.

Answer (score 0):

The [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) in `B1` below

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formulae]

is

```
=LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(CHAR(96+COLUMN(A1:Z1)),A1),1)-3)
```

and the array formula in `C1` is

```
=MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(CHAR(96+COLUMN(A1:Z1)),A1),1)-1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1))
```